# Does a RequestDispatcher forward maintain the original request's HTTP method?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to intercept a request using the RequestDispatcher, and then I want to forward the request along to another servlet -- something like this:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet/some.ThirdPartyServlet" + "?" + "param_name=" + "somevalue");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

If the incoming request were a POST, will the request dispatcher take my new parameters, and include them in the message body, or does this forward now become a GET?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It retains the original request, without changing it.

So, it will remain POST if it was POST.

Answer (score 18):

I think your concern is rather the availability of the passed-in request **parameters** (not attributes as others mentions). In this case it doesn't matter whether you use a forward or a redirect. But if you use a forward to another `Servlet`, then the appropriate method associated with the initial request as obtained by `HttpServletRequest#getMethod()` will be invoked. If it is POST, then `doPost()` will be invoked. You can still access the additional parameters in the query string the usual way by `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`.

So basically the following in servlet1:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2?foo=bar").forward(request, response);
}
```

can basically be handled by servlet2 as follows:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String foo = request.getParameter("foo"); // Returns "bar".
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use forward, then control stays within the servlet container, the request attributes are retained, and the request remains a POST. It's when you use redirect that it causes a response to be sent to the browser causing it to make a GET request, which is where it loses the request attributes for the original request because the GET is an entirely new request.