# RequestDispatcher forward from one doPost will always go to another doPost only?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I guess I am having trouble understanding how the request dispatcher will work in a scenario. I am just trying to understand how Servlets interact and how different methods within it are called.

**Login.html**

```
<form action="LoginHandling" method="post">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="one" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="two" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

**Servlet handling Login.html**

```
@WebServlet("/LoginHandling")
public class LoginHandling extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    session.setAttribute("user", username);
    session.setAttribute("pass", password); 
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WelcomeServlet");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

**WelcomeServlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String userIs = (String)session.getAttribute("user");
    String passwordEntered = (String)session.getAttribute("pass");

    if (passwordEntered.equals("accept")) {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>");
        out.println("Welcome,"+ userIs);
        out.println("</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h2>Welcome, "+userIs+"</h2>"+"<br>");
        out.println("<p>This is the welcome page of our application</p><br><br>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Error.html");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

So all I did was ask dispatcher to forward request to `/WelcomeServlet` but how does it recognize that it is the `doPost()` method in that servlet which needs to get called? Is it because I only have a `doPost()` in the `/WelcomeServlet`, which causes it to behave like that? What if there was a `doGet()`, `doPut()` or `doDelete()`? How will I communicate with a specific method as per my requirement from one method in a Servlet to another different method in another different Servlet, example `doGet()` from Servlet 1 to `doPut()` of Servlet 2? Maybe I am not understanding forward method of `RequestDispatcher` correctly. How using include be different? I am just trying to understand inter-servlet communication by using HTML pages for now, and then will soon move to JSPs with Servlets. Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a RequestDispatcher forward maintain the original request's HTTP method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940306/does-a-requestdispatcher-forward-maintain-the-original-requests-http-method)

Comment: It is because you are submitting the form (using POST) which is mapped to the Servlet `LoginHandling`. This original requests (POST) remains and is merely forwarded to another Servlet - `RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WelcomeServlet");`. If you  would however, use `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("...")`, you would see `doGet()` being invoked - status code 303 is sent to the browser and the browser sends a brand new GET request to the said URL (which is passed as a parameter to `sendRedirect()`).