# How to forward from POST to GET handler

Tags: spring

I need to forward from a POST to a GET request.

Somehow I end up in an endless loop. It always goes to the POST handler. Of course GET and POST have the same URL . But that's normal in REST design.

So how can I forward to the GET handler. Also in the error case I need to have redirectAttributs to have the error attributes available in the GET method .

That is my code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/holiday", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String holiday(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("holiday", new Holiday());
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);

    List<Holiday> lstHoliday = holidayDao.findByUser(userDao.findByUserName(Util.getLoggedInUserName()));

    model.addAttribute("Util", new Util());

    model.addAttribute("holidaylist", lstHoliday);

    model.addAttribute("residualLeave",Util.calculateResidualHoliday(lstHoliday));

    return "/user/holiday";
}

    @PostMapping(value = "/user/holiday")
    public String holidayPost(Model model,  Holiday holiday,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) throws ParseException {

        DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter .ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

        holiday.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        holiday.setFirstDay(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(holiday.getStringFirstDay()));
        holiday.setLastDay(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(holiday.getStringLastDay()));

        holiday.setNumberOfDays(Util.calculateNumberOfDays(holiday.getFirstDay(), holiday.getLastDay()));

        holiday.setUser(userDao.findByUserName(Util.getLoggedInUserName()));

        List<Holiday> lstHoliday = holidayDao.findByUser(userDao.findByUserName(Util.getLoggedInUserName()));

        if(holiday.getNumberOfDays()> Util.calculateResidualHoliday(lstHoliday))
        {
            redirectAttrs.addAttribute("hasError", true);
            redirectAttrs.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Die Anzahl an Urlaubstagen ist größer als Ihr Resturlaub !!");
            return "forward:/user/holiday";
        }

        holidayDao.save(holiday);
        return "redirect:/user/holiday";
    }
```

The funny thing is , the redirect works when the holiday can be saved. It only does not work when there is an error so it is in the if block.

Comment: you are forwarding on error and not redirecting

Comment: Yes on error I want to forward. But why I always end up in the POST handler ?? Actually I could forward in both cases I think. Why should I redirect at all. That takes just longer. Right ?

Comment: with forward the original request get forwarded , which is a POST here and results in loop

Comment: Yeah I just saw this. If I exchange redirect with forward in the normal case (non error) then I end up in an endless loop again. With redirect I get to the GET Handler. With forward to the POST Handler. Weird.

Comment: That is by design. Please read on redirect and forward

Comment: So how can I get to the GET handler :)

Comment: If it is because you need the redirect attributes on error , the model of the target url will have those attributes .

Comment: so now I use Flash attribute and finally I have the attributes availiable in the GET handler. STill it is very annoying that I have to use redirect here. Forward is not working. I do not know why a forward to a POST would makes sense. Normally you always forward or redirect to GET . If my GET Url would be named differently than my POST Url maybe it would work. So it just does not make sense to me why forward goes to POST .

Comment: the original request  was an http POST . This request is fowarded which again is an http POST and will come to the same controller method. you may forward the request to another endpoint , which again should be accepting an Http POST.

Comment: Why should a POST forward to a POST. It's more common to forward from POST to GET. But if by design forward always looks for same method. Ok. Then that's how it is.

Comment: This [q & a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1940306/4214241) might help you